# Angular JS + CoffeeScript + JSFiddle: Code not working

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jsfiddle

I started playing around with CoffeeScript and AngularJS today and noticed that there is not a whole lot of documentation or examples on how to correctly write AngularJS using CoffeeScript. My own experimentation with it seems not to be working. As a pedagogical excersice, could someone point me as to why this is fiddle is not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/dralexmv/8km8x/4/

It claims the InventoryModule is not defined. Although I have declared it in the first line.

This is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app='InventoryModule' ng-controller='InventoryController'>
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the CoffeeScript:

```
inventoryModule = angular.module 'InventoryModule', []

inventoryModule.factory 'Items', ->
    items = {}
    items.query -> [
        {title: 'Table', price: '5'},
        {title: 'Chair', price: '10'}
    ]
    items

inventoryModule.controller 'InventoryController', ($scope, Items) ->
    $scope.items = Items.query
```

Comment: JSFiddle its supposed to add it in the markup automatically when selecting Angular as a Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code contains the following

```
items.query -> [{title: 'Hello', price: '5'}]
```

Which translates to:

```
  var items = {};
  items.query(function() { // Items has no method query
    return [{
        title: 'Hello',
        price: '5'
      }];
  });
```

What you meant, is to define a member as a function, so it should be:

```
items.query = () -> [{title: 'Hello', price: '5'}]
```

Which translates to:

```
  var items = {};

  items.query = function() {
    return [{
        title: 'Hello',
        price: '5'
      }];
  };
```

Which is what you meant :)

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLmtW/))

Comment: I see. Tricky CoffeeScript syntax I am still getting used to.

Comment: @AlexanderVentura I'm glad I could help. If it helps I've done, and seen AngularJS +CoffeeScript development and it's very nice :)

Comment: One last thing, when I change the `$scope.items` to `$scope.items = Items.query` the page still does not parse. Why is that?

Comment: @AlexanderVentura How would it know if it's a call or an assignment? There are no parameters :) You can try `$scope.items = Items.query()`

Comment: I see, I tried to keep it as a purist CoffeeScript syntax. Thanks again.